# Missing SVG icons after publishing VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My extension uses two SVG images to navigate/refresh inside of vscode. [View Image](https://pasteboard.co/IfRqpYG.png)

All works fine and dandy in the debugger but the published versions do not show the [SVG images](https://pasteboard.co/IfRqjjF.png)?

Here is how I set them inside my `package.json`:

```json
"commands": [
    {
        "command": "live-workspace.refresh",
        "title": "Refresh",
        "icon": {
            "dark": "./src/media/darkReload.svg",
            "light": "./src/media/lightReload.svg"
        }
    }
]
```

and:

```json
"viewsContainers": {
    "activitybar": [
        {
            "id": "live-workspace",
            "title": "Live-Workspace",
            "icon": "./src/media/laptop.svg"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a `GET()` error in the developers tools console as you may see from the image.. Any idea what causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the images were not actually shipped with the release.

The default [`.vscodeignore`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#.vscodeignore) file from the VSCode extension template has, among  other things, the following line to avoid any source files unnecessarily being included in releases:

```
src/**
```

I suggest you simply move the images elsewhere, as the `src` directory isn't really a good fit for this. The common convention seems to be to have a separate `images` or `resources` directory.